linearly independent vectors over $\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to linearly independent vectors over $\mathbb{R}$
Let $D$ be a discrete subgroup of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. I want to prove that if $\{v_1,\ldots,v_s\}\subset D$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}$ then it is also linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$.  If any hint to do so.

independEnt. A "pendant" is something you wear on a chain around your neck.

What have you tried so far?

@ArturoMagidin Is that group discrete?

@MartinBrandenburg Guess it wasn't. I'll need to review the definition before trying to answer other questions like this one.

Any such discrete subgroup is a free, i.e., there are vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_k \in V$, with $1\le k\le \dim V$, such that $D= \mathbb Z u_1+ \cdots+\mathbb Z u_k$. See this answer for a proof: Discrete subgroups of $\mathbb R^n$ are free
Let $A$ be the $k\times s$ integer matrix such that $A_{ij}$ is the coefficient of $u_i$ in $v_j$.
If the vectors are linearly dependent in $V$, then there is a nontrivial real solution to the matrix equation $A x=0$. But then, there must be a rational solution too. See this answer for a proof: System of linear equations having a real solution has also a rational solution.
By scaling the rational solution, you can get an integer solution too. But this contradicts the fact that the vectors are linearly independent in $D$. Therefore, the vectors are linearly independent in $V$ too.
